# The name 'ActionIcon' does not exist in the current context but it is

Tags: asp.net, listview

I got an error with my code saying at ActionIcon does not exist in current context, but I am pretty sure it is....here is my code behind

What Am I doing wrong?

`

```
                              <a class="LinkButtonBlueSmall" name="ApproveBtn"
                                 onclick="ChangeOne('Approve','<%#ActionIcon.ClientID %>');">
                                 Approve</a>

                              <a class="LinkButtonOrangeSmall" name="RejectBtn"
                                 onclick="ChangeOne('Reject', '<%#ActionIcon.ClientID %>');">
                                 Reject</a>

                              <a class="LinkButtonMutedSmall" name="ClearBtn"
                                 onclick="ChangeOne('Clear', '<%#ActionIcon.ClientID %>');">
                                 Clear</a>

                              </span>
                            </td>`
```

Comment: You need to post your markup to so we can see where ActionIcon's being created.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML where you use the ActionItem?

Comment: There you go, i had to take out my previous code as it was too long